# Why do our WiFi APs kick people off randomly while still serving others?

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, wireless-access-point

We have an ADSL modem/router/WiFi AP connected to Telefónica in Spain.  Maximum speed measured is a little less than 8 MBps.  Call this #1.

Cat 5e cable from one of its LAN ports feeds a TP-Link router/AP (LAN port) set to access point mode.    Call this #2.

Cat 5e cable from one of those LAN ports feeds another TP-Link router/AP (LAN port) which does not offer access point mode.  Call this #3.

When we tried to let them all get DHCP from #1, #2 & #3 didn't work.  So all three are doing DHCP with non-overlapping address ranges.  Each has a different SSID and password.  #1 and #3 are far enough apart that we can never see both at the same time in these four-hundred-year-old stone buildings.  They are for staff.  #2 is for guests, approximately halfway between #1 and #3.

All connect to internet normally most of the time.  But with no apparent pattern, one user will get disconnected OR remain connected but with on internet access.  Other users on the same AP will still be OK.  Or occasionally, one AP disconnects **everyone** while the other two continue to work.  #1 sometimes asks a user to re-enter a password, and sometimes says it is the wrong password.  Sometimes the problem goes away after a while; sometimes the router must be rebooted.

They had IGMP on by default, but I turned it when installing #2 & #3.  I also set both to WPA2.

The #1 was here before I arrived; I turned IGMP off on it today, and changed it from WEP to WPA2.

The problem does not appear to be related to signal strength.  It happens even when close to the AP.

Give all that, any guesses as to what is going on?

UPDATE: Getting weirder, I mentioned above that I fixed the DHCP overlap, fixed the weak authentication, and turned off IGMP on the upstream router (#1).  Since then (one exception), there have been no problems on that router or the next one downstream.  But the exception—one laptop that was doing OK before the fix **always** says it is not connected, when the router log says it connected, was offered IP address 192.168.13x, and accepted it.  Same laptop still connects OK to the second (guest) AP.

DOS window on that laptop, when connected to the guest router: ipconfig shows an IP address in that router's DHCP range, but says "preferred 100" in parentheses.  100 is not in that router's range, but it **is** in the range for #1.  This is Windows 10, and I can't find the place I used on earlier versions to check DNS, DHCP, and IP (static/dynamic) settings.

Another update: Turns out that the one exception is (apparently) because Windows “remembered” that the connection is WEP and although it connected initially, it wouldn’t do the things needed to run with WPA.  When I deleted the profile (had to go to DOS to do it), then it let us connect again with the password.  But the third AP in the chain is still intermittently discriminating against users.

Comment: It sounds like you might have a session timeout setting enabled. Can you advise what APs you have?

Comment: I have already enter this comment twice.  Why does it keep disappearing?  #1 in the admin webserver identifies as "OBSERVA TELECOM, AW4062" and the other two are _new_ TP-link but not the same model.  #1 is at least three years old and provided by the phone company.  I saw no place to change a session timeout.  I would expect default to be reasonable.  I've set up a lot of routers and APs and have never seen any other do what these three are doing.